# Performance issue using GSAP and ScrollMagic

Tags: javascript, svg, gsap, scrollmagic

I'm currently building a website with GSAP's TimelineMax, MorphSVG plugin and ScrollMagic.

I'm facing jitter effect sometimes and this warning comes out :

*`Handling of 'mousewheel' input event was delayed for 163 ms due to main thread being busy. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responive.`*

I have 1 ScrollMagic Controller and 4 Scenes attached.

My main performance issue doesn't seem to be related to ScrollMagic because that's on a mousewheel svg morph that I'm doing without it like this :

```
// GSAP Morph tween
self.tl.to(".chapter1 #assembled .logo", 2, {morphSVG:"#exploded .logo", fill: '#18c5a3'})
.from(".chapter1 #assembled .logo", 1, {opacity: 1})
.to(".chapter1 #assembled .logo", 1, {opacity: 0})

// Progress the tween on mousewheel
function handleUnbuild () {
    self.tl.progress(window.pageYOffset/500).pause()
}
window.addEventListener('mousewheel', handleUnbuild, {passive: true})
```

Without ScrollMagic then...I tried to attach this tween to a SM scene but I couldn't figure out how to do it.

**Note that the animation jitter on my main screen (Macbook pro 13") but is fine on my second wider screen and this is so wierd.**

Comment: Use a throttle when listening to the mouse wheel or scroll.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Throttle does not change my framerate but I figure out what caused that drop. I was applying a scale change while my svg morphed. It's way better without but this is not explaining the difference between screens.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [lodash throttle documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#throttle), the example is exactly what you need (same for underscore). It'll prevent the event from firing too many times. I guess you could also use a RAF in `handleUnbuild()`.

Concerning the fact that it only happens on your MBP, it's probably performances related (as your second screen is not Retina I guess).